# Transform nested List

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I need to merge two different `List`s, one of which is nested inside a class. There are my current classes:

```
Class B {
   int b;
}

Class A {
    int a;
    List <B> bs;   
}
```

My `List` data structure is like this:

```
List<A> as;
```

How can I transform them to look something like this?

```
List<C> ac;

Class C {
 int a; //property class A
 int b; //property class B
}
```

Each `bs` property element `A` in `List<A> as` have the same length, 
so if I have 2 elements `A`, there will also be 2 elements `B`, and I will have 4 element `C`s.

Comment: Can't you do this with nested loops?  Have an outer loop that iterates through the `List<A>` and an inner loop that iterates through each `List<B>`.  Then inside the inner loop, have a line of code that makes a new `C` and adds it to the `List<C>`.  This seems rather straightforward.  Did you write any code yet?

Comment: @DawoodIbnKareem You should write your answer as an answer, not a comment! That way others can see it, and you'll get credit.

Comment: @Keara, no, that would not be consistent with Stack Overflow's intention not to be a code writing service.  The OP has failed to write an adequate question, because there is no attempt at a solution yet.  Essentially, it's just a request for code - and we don't entertain those on Stack Overflow.  Moreover, if anyone _does_ answer this, I'll probably downvote it.

Comment: @DawoodIbnKareem Fair enough, that's a good point.

Comment: I've made an edit to generally fix question structure, formatting, grammar :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate through the as List, in each iteration you then iterate through the bs List at which point you create a C object and add it to ac list.

As has been mentioned, if you're looking for code to be written for you, this is probably not the right place to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably create a constructor in C:

```
C(A a, B b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
```

Then

```
List<C> cs = as.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.bs.stream()
            .map(b -> new C(a, b)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For every `a` a stream if `c`s is made. And `flatMap` reduces them in one large stream of `c`s.